# Using a Service Account with Google Analytics .Net API v3.0

Tags: .net, api, authentication, google-analytics

Ok, I can't possibly be the only one... I've looked high and low on SO and elsewhere and come up empty handed. I am attempting to use a service account with the latest Google Analytics dotNet API (v3.0). The examples I have found are all using the Web or Installed Application methods, OR they are not using the dotNet API (Usually PHP), OR they are referencing an earlier version of the API (v3 is NOT backward compatible). My app works great when I register it (and authenticate) with the Web Application method - except for the request to allow access that pops up every time I run it.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/oauth2-dev/oa378p9Ukm8/YKWnUcawF7wJ from Claudio